# Django registration does not authenticate costum hash passwords

Tags: django, authentication

In the process of migrating a drupal site to django, I am using [this](http://pastebin.com/tfXimPRD) snippet which replicate Drupal 7 password hashing for django. I tested it in shell and it works correctly there:

```
>>> h.verify("dodo", "$S$DgFuhvuSb/ZVKW9JnPsjV.ht4z8MzeIrpLTiqPV9pBWU7AajfD.D")
True
```

I use [django-registration](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) module. When I have implemented the snippet as per explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28080741/727695) the old drupal users still fail to authenticate, and django-registration complains that:

> Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields
>   may be case-sensitive.

I have no such problem for users which are created in django, hence I assume there is something wrong with my implementation of the snippet.

How to troubleshoot and fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to use a `pdb` or similar to step through the login process?

Comment: It's a module in the standard library that lets you step through your code line by line. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: [Pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb) and [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) are improved versions of pdb.

Comment: Thanks for the hints about pdb but in the django-registration docs I don't see any instructions about how to test. Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: I usually use runserver, and then put `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` in my view or model I want to investigate. When you load the page in the browser, the debugger pauses at the breakpoint, and I step through the code from the runserver shell.

Comment: Did you read ? or followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086413/cant-authenticate-with-custom-password-hashers

Comment: @Raja, I read it but not sure how the link you mentioned is related to my question. Would you elaborate please?

Comment: @supermario ok you told that you verified through shell , that's fine. And If it's working through shell then it ll work with app too . But i don't think the problem with django-registration.

Comment: @Raja, That's why I'm so perplexed. It works on shell but not on browser.

Comment: @supermario Me too experienced with this before but i don't know how i solved . ! But just checking ( I don't know this is correct way ) i moved my custom `drupal_hasher` to the top then i experienced different behavior. But before that you should take backup , bcse moving this cause lot of trouble .

Comment: @Raja, have you been using django-registration? If not how did you authenticate users?

Comment: @supermario I never used that, I wrote all the things myself becse this way I like & I learn ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69449/discussion-between-raja-and-supermario).